# Invalid output constraint "=d" in asm when building GLIB for arm32(Windows)

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors, inline-assembly

I'm trying to build GLIB and I'm cross compiling it (for Windows on ARM32), but when it gets to valgrind.h/gslice.c, it fails saying:

```
error: invalid output constraint '=d' in asm
```

I've looked around but I've seen nobody have the issue of "=d" failing, ever. The compiler is LLVM-MinGW (clang10/llvm/lld based MinGW toolchain), Linux distribution is Pop!_OS 20.04, everything's updated. Any help's appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to cross-compile x86 asm to ARM. That won't work. Make sure the proper asm variant is used, or a fallback C implementation if one is available.

Comment: Alright! I'll see if there's a fallback C implementation or ARM ASM in it. Thanks!

Comment: Apparently valgrind.h starts out with a bunch of platform detection code. You likely want to tweak those so that ARM is detected. It does have `PLAT_arm_linux`

Comment: That worked! Thanks a ton!

Comment: You have an ARM system, and you're using it to cross-compile for x86 Windows?  `"=d"` should work for an x86 target regardless of host.  Or if you mean you're trying to compile for ARM-Windows, then yeah the code is buggy and is trying to use x86 asm.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything defining `__GNUC__` supports flag outputs
from asm statements;
in particular, some Clang versions
on macOS does not.

The correct test per the GCC documentation
is `__GCC_ASM_FLAG_OUTPUTS__`, so use that instead.

see the details in patch here:
https://github.com/google/snappy/commit/8dd58a519f79f0742d4c68fbccb2aed2ddb651e8

Comment: True, but `"=d"` isn't a flag-condition output, those look like `"=@ccz"`, with the `@cc` indicating a condition-code.  `"=d"` is a constraint that picks x86's EDX register, or might have other meanings on other ISAs, but apparently not on ARM.